# Same GLUT application using single and double buffer?

Tags: c, glut

Can I have a GLUT program with one of the windows with single buffer while the other uses double buffer?

The display mode can be set using the `glutInitDisplayMode()` but how to set it differently to different windows?
I tried using the `glutSetWindow()`, but either one of the two windows does not work.

Answer (score 2):

`glutInitDisplayMode` sets the mode that will be used for the next window that is created. Therefore you can call it multiple times, once for each window:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
int id0 = glutCreateWindow("double buffered");
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
int id1 = glutCreateWindow("single buffered");
```

Alternatively, you can temporarily turn off double buffering by directly drawing onto the front buffer.

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT);
// ... single buffered drawing ...

glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);  // switch back to double buffered
```